# If I generate a model in string, anywhere to get the selector button in the string?

Tags: jquery

```
var $div = "<div id=\"success\" class=\"modal hide fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" data-backdrop=\"true\" role=\"dialog\"><div class=\"modal-header btn-primary\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">×</button><h3>Success</h3></div><div class=\"modal-body\"><p>Update Success, continue?</p></div><div class=\"modal-footer\"><button class=\"btn\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Yes</button><button class=\"btn\" id=\"no\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">No</button></div></div>";
                $($div).appendTo('body').modal("show");

$('#no').on('Click', function(){

});
```

Anywhere to click the #no selector?

Comment: You wan to gain knowledge? Don't put HTML into a JavaScript string like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegated events:

```
$(document).on('click', '#no', function() {
    ...
});
```

#### [Check the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: thanks, I dont know what is the keyword to search for, SO just the prefect place to gain knowledge